# Problem with Free SMTP Server in php code

Tags: php, email, smtp

I wrote php  code for use to contact us form

but I can not find free SMTP server to use it.

I Try to use SMTP Server For Gmail but I found this error.

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]:
>   "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or
>   custom "From:" header missing in
>   C:\www\htdocs\contactUs.php on line
>   25"

line 25 is :

```
mail ($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
```

statement that indicate using Gmail SMTP Server is :

```
ini_set("SMTP","smtp.gmail.com");
```

SO,can U help me ?:(

Comment: Set the sendmail_from in php.ini.

Oh, wait, that's what the message already tells you ...

Comment: Sorry ,
can you tell me how ? :)

I set it in php code between php tags!!

Answer (score 0):

You need a `From: [VALID EMAIL]` header of the message when you send the message. Try doing something like this:

```
$headers = array(
    'From: me@example.com',
    'Mime-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8',
);

$dest = 'some_user@example.com';
$subj = 'test';

$message = 'hello world';

mail($dest, $subj, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Also, the `mail` function is meant to be used as a frontend to the mail daemon that's running on the same server the web server is running on. Since most *NIX boxes have both, it usually works.

What I would not recommend, however, is using some remote server to send your mail. It's much more efficient and reliable (not to mention looking more professional) to just have the same server send the message as the one that generated the message.

Setting up your own SMTP server is easy and free and more flexible than Gmail. Gmail ***WILL NOT*** send messages whose `From:` header does not match either the main account address or a connected address.